# Storing things on the SD card

Tags: applications, sd-card

I have successfully moved the Facebook app like 10 times from device storage to SD card (and the same is true for some other apps), but a few days later I try to install something and I get "insufficient storage".  When I look, Facebook is back in the device storage not the SD card (same with some other apps).  Any idea what is happening?  Most apps I moved stayed there, but some mysteriously move back.

Answer (score 0):

This is common when you have automatic updated turned on, or the app set to auto update... When the update installs it places it in the default installation location, typically internal storage, and deletes it from the SD card.

Comment: And I reckon we can't change that?

Comment: @Tony I reckon you can change the update settings, both globally and per app. On some devices you can change the default installation location and not on others, it is usually in storage or app settings, but you never said what device.

Comment: I think I have to type a lot of words before I can answer so I apologize for the long sentence.  It is a Galaxy S4